# how to pick items from different list inside for loop?

Tags: python

i have two list and i want to use items from both lists inside for loop

here's my code

```
list1 = ['a','b','c']
list2 = ['1','2','3']

for x in list1:
    print(x)
    for y in list2:
        print(y)
```

This is what it prints

```
a
1
2
3
b
1
2
3
c
1
2
3
```

this is want i want it to print

```
a
1
b
2
c
3
```

Answer (score 2):

```
list1 = ['a','b','c']
list2 = ['1','2','3']

for x,y in zip(list1,list2):
    print(x)
    print(y)
```

zip iterates the lists together.

Comment: Welcome! Glad to help